# MySQL query optimization and indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table with a an indexed "create_at" field. I need to do some aggregation queries but I don't understand with using the index to reduce the range is not effective.

**All the table :**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM subscriptions
```

=> 412288 rows

**Only 2011 year :**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM subscriptions
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59')
```

=> 95217 rows

**Aggregate 2011 year by monthes :**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MONTH(created_at) AS agg_created_at, SUM(amount) AS agg_amount 
FROM subscriptions
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY agg_created_at
ORDER BY agg_created_at
```

=> 0.1398 sec

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+                                                                                                         
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |                                                                                                         
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+                                                                                                         
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscriptions | ALL  | created_at    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 422807 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |                                                                                                         
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**Same query with force index :**

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE MONTH(created_at) AS agg_created_at, SUM(amount) AS agg_amount 
FROM subscriptions FORCE INDEX(created_at)
WHERE (created_at BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59') 
GROUP BY agg_created_at
ORDER BY agg_created_at
```

=> 0.1283 sec

```
 +----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscriptions | range | created_at    | created_at | 8       | NULL | 194106 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The optimizer seems clever here because using the index to reduce the range is ineffective but I don't understand why. If someone has an explanation ?

Comment: How is it ineffective? The runtime is smaller when you force the index...unless I am not understanding...

Comment: I mean it is quite the same. On several runs it can be a bit lower or a bit higher.